# Extracting .zip folder through PuTTy causes internal error 500

Tags: putty, file-permissions, website, cpanel, unzip

fairly new to this side of the world.
I am experiencing a weird situation. I succeeded to connect to a cPanel account through WinCSP, using CSP protocol and I am using PuTTY to run commands, like unzip a compressed folder.

When I unzip the folder using Putty, then the website will return internal error 500. 
When I unzip the same folder using cPanel feature, it all works fine.

I suppose it is a matter of permissions. Putty seems to assign 775 to all folders and files, whereas cPanel assigns 750.

Any clue, please?